# What is the reason behind precision and scale naming?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sybase

I have a lot of troubles understanding why precision and scale are called that way in database types.

I see precision and scale differently.

**PRECISION IN MY POINT OF VIEW**

For me precision would be how many digits there are in the right side. For instance, *1* is less precise than *1,0001*.

**SCALE IN MY POINT OF VIEW**

Scale would be how much a number can go up or down. 
For instance *0 - 1000* is a bigger scale than *0 - 10*.
Or even *0 - 1,0* is a bigger scale than *0 - 1*.

**PRECISION AND SCALE IN DATABASE**

However in database lexicon it has different meaning, precision is the total of digits in a number and scale the number of digits on right.

I'm always forgetting the meaning of this two words because I can't make sense of them.

Hope you guys can help me out, understanding why they are called this way

Comment: This is probably going to be seen as off topic for SO. At the end of the day, that's what they're called. You don't question why an apple is called an apple; that's what it's called. When whomever chose the names for the parameters for `numeric`, that is what they chose.

Comment: Think "significant figures" for precision, and "power of 10 to divide by" for scale (as in, how much to scale the number *by*, not what scale it represents itself). The person who named these things was probably thinking more in terms of implementation.

Comment: Some databases even use precision and scale in "bits" not "decimal digits" -- just wanted to add to the confusion.

Comment: Many CS terms have clear historic origins. I honestly think this question may have a answer.

Comment: 1.0001 is more precise than 1 since it provides more information. If you consider rounding on numbers, a wider range of numbers can round to just 1, vs those that can round to 1.0001 - the more digits, the more information, and the more precise (or granular is another way of thinking it) you are being.

Comment: Surely off topic, but your answer is in here somewhere: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Converting_from_single-precision_binary_to_decimal

Comment: Maybe wikipedia can shed some light https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic -- though "scale" is related to "exponent" there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you would have the people who came up with the name.

Comment: Note that `numeric` is decimal floating point, while `float` and `real` are binary floating point. "Precision" doesn't mean the same thing for both, which is what I think a bunch of comments are alluding to. For binary floating point, the precision is the number of bits used to store the mantissa, which is not at all the same as the number of significant digits. (Speaking strictly in the context of how SQL Server and I presume also Sybase uses these terms.)

Comment: This isn't just a database thing. E.g. look at [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Precision.html) to see that what you're calling "precision" is referred to mathematically as *accuracy* whereas what the database is calling "precision" is referred to mathematically as ... *precision*.

Comment: Numbers to the left is your definition of scale.

Comment: @Larnu those are not fair comparisions. An apple is a apple, and a banana is a banana, if you call a banana of apple than it is legit you can question why someone is calling a banana of apple.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Hey! it makes sense that way! :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I also believe that, I think we will find the answer here :)

Comment: @TheImpaler thank you for your contribution, Good link. helped me out! :)

Comment: @SeanLange There is always someone who came up with the names, but not everybody knows why. Now that I know the answer my performance will improve because I'll be able of remembering this words definitions. So this question is as valid as any other.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for your contribution Damien, I understand what you are saying about precision! But they are also calling accuracy to what database calls scale. Either way at this stage I already understood that this are not terms solely of databases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's easier if you consider how the numbers look in scientific notation.

```
X * 10^Y
```

where X has a single digit before the decimal point.

Now, how big the number is (its "scale") is fundamentally determined by `Y`.  Are we counting in ones?  Millions?  Thousandths?  That's scale.

Regardless of the absolute scale of the number, the digits in `X` determine how precise we're being.  Can I distinguish 1.1 ones from 1.2 ones?  Can I distinguish 1.1 millions from 1.2 millions?  Can I distinguish 1.1 thousandths from 1.2 thousandths?  All are equivalent - two digits (including the one before the decimal point) of precision.

If I can distinguish 1.01 millions from 1.00 millions, that's more precise than only being able to distinguish 0.1 millions; that's 3 digits of precision.

But 1.01*10^-3 is *not* more precise than 1.01*10^10 ; it merely operates at a smaller scale.

Beyond that, I don't know what you want.  Ok, you've told us what you'd like the words to mean; but that's not what they mean.  This is what they mean.

---

*UPDATE* - One other thing I should mention.  It may seem that scale and precision are conflated in some way, because if we take a physical example, surely "1 millimeter from the bullseye" is more precise than "1 meter from the bullseye", right?

But remember that precision and scale describe a *variable's data type*, not a specific measurement.  If measuring in meters, we can't *express* "1 millimeter from the bullseye" with less than 4 digits of precision ("0.001 meters"); but we could describe "1 meter from the bullseye" with 1 digit of precision.  So that actually does align with our desire to call "1 mm from the bullseye" somehow more precise.

Comment: I did't told what I would like the words to mean, I told my understanding of the words. And asked for help to find the right meaning for this domain. Thing that you contribute positively, as well as other guys in comment section. Thanks :)